# index match second value

Tags: indexing, match

Okay so, i've created a spreadsheet to learn and develop the things i need.
i've done so much, then got stuck.
i have a value i'm trying to index match, the first works, but i can't get the second value no matter what i do.
the first cell contains this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(A2:R4,SMALL(IF(A2:A4=A11,ROW(A2:A4)),ROW(1:1)),11)),"NOPE",INDEX(A2:R4,SMALL(IF(A2:A4=A11,ROW(A2:A4)),ROW(1:1)),11))
```

with ctlr shift enter to create the array.

the second contains:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(A2:R4,SMALL(IF(A2:A4=A11,ROW(A2:A4)),ROW(2:2)),11)),"NOPE",INDEX(A2:R4,SMALL(IF(A2:A4=A11,ROW(A2:A4)),ROW(2:2)),11))
```

I HAVE DUPLICATE VALUES I'VE CHECKED 1000 TIMES.
I've only posted here once before and i got told to google etc, and i have done that till my fingers hurt but i can't get this to work. 
any suggestions

the second should show the 2nd result row(2:2) but i get an N/A result, or NOPE as in my formula. so i have two duplicate values and i want the results from column number 11. the first formula provides the first result, i'm trying to obtain the second. they are close to identical, with the exception of the row (the two formulas that is). i'm still new so i apologise if this doesn't make to much sense, googled most of my excel and sql life.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The two expressions are identical, are they not? Is that the problem or did you mean them to be different?

Comment: the second should show the 2nd result row(2:2) but i get an N/A result, or NOPE as in my formula. so i have two duplicate values and i want the results from column number 11. the first formula provides the first result, i'm trying to obtain the second. they are close to identical, with the exception of the row (the two formulas that is). i'm still new so i apologise if this doesn't make to much sense, googled most of my excel and sql life.

Comment: just figured out to comment to you rather than edit, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(A2:R4,SMALL(IF(A2:A4=A11,ROW(A2:A4)),ROW(2:2))-1,11)),"NOPE",INDEX(A2:R4,SMALL(IF(A2:A4=A11,ROW(A2:A4)),ROW(2:2))-1,11))

I figured it out, hours and hours, probably due to league of legends and vodka interrupting.  the above worked for me. thank the heavens.

I hope this might help others also.

Comment: it seems with the 2:2 I had to add the -1